# FTPS login error: Invalid sequence of commands (AUTH SSL/TLS required prior to authentication)

Tags: java, ssl, ftp

I am getting the following error when using myjavaworld ftp client to connect to a ftp server.

> com.myjavaworld.ftp.FTPException: Invalid sequence of commands (AUTH SSL/TLS required prior to authentication).

It used to work fine until they changed their ftp server.

Here is my code:

```
FTPClient ftp = (FTPClient) Class.forName("com.myjavaworld.ftp.DefaultFTPClient").newInstance(); 
SSLContext sslContext =    SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2"); 
sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{new MyTrustmanager()}, null);
ftp.setSSLContext(sslContext); ftp.setSSLUsage(FTPConstants.USE_SSL_IF_AVAILABLE);
ftp.connect(host);
ftp.login(username, password);
```

Comment: Try to use [setSSLUsage](https://www.jmethods.com/releases/secure-ftp-api-for-java/3.0.0/apidocs/com/myjavaworld/ftp/FTPClient.html#setSSLUsage(int)) to `USE_EXPLICIT_SSL` after `setSSLContext`.

Comment: Thanks I’ve tried that also but hen I get the following error: com.my Java world.ftp.FTPException: Protocol not supported. Can you tell me if such error is coming from ftp server or it is the JVM reporting that?